# adding comma to each line using sublime text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I am trying to use sublime's text search and replace function and regex to match a string of number in each line and append a comma to each. So here's the sample file:

```
 273794103
 418892296
 134582886
 380758661
 109829186
 248050497
 2167935715
 374858669
```

I want this to be:

```
 273794103,
 418892296,
 134582886,
 380758661,
 109829186,
 248050497,
 2167935715,
 374858669,
```

I tried doing this `(\d+)\n` and replacing it with `$1,` but this doesn't work. Any idea why?
FYI for those who are not into sublime but into regex, Sublime Text uses Python's regex engine.

Comment: **For VS Code** :  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76730790/2218697) post.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I'd recommend this

**'Find What'**: `$` // matching all ends of your lines
**'Replace With'**: `,` // replaces all line ends with a coma

this will work with any file :-)

Comment: Make sure you enable regex

Comment: sorry to say, but it not selecting anything , I am using eclipse in mac.

Comment: ehm... this answer is about Sublime Text as mentioned in the subject ;-)

Comment: **For VS Code** :  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76730790/2218697) post.

Answer (score 236):

To add comma to any line

1. Select the lines you want to modify
2. `CTRL + SHIFT + L`
3. `RIGHT_ARROW`
4. `COMMA`

Using ctrl + shift + L is how you can modify all selected lines. Very handy :-)

Comment: and to get rid of the line breaks:
5. RIGHT_ARROW
6. DELETE
7. SPACE

Comment: For Mac it is CMD, Shift, L or 'Split into Lines' in the 'Selection' menu.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: This is the better answer. Knowing how to use this is far faster for the majority of tasks in this vein.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this. Wasted a bunch of time trying to write my own macro when there was already an easy way to do it..

Comment: easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: Perfect, saved time!

Comment: Perfect! this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: **For VS Code** :  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76730790/2218697) post.

Answer (score 19):

Here's how you'd do it on a Mac:

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>L</kbd> > <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> > *Comma*

and [Windows/Linux](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/selection):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>L</kbd> > <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> > *Comma*

Comment: Thank you for specifying for other OS's

Answer (score 6):

For Window User:

1. select all line OR select part of line  => Ctrl+A.
2. Bring cursor to last of each Line => Ctrl+Shift+L
3. Add comma(,) which will reflect to all line.

** If you want to add comma(,) at start of each Line , After step 2 press => Home(button from keyboard , all cursors will head to start of the line)

Finally Ctrl+s to save the changes.

cheers

Answer (score 5):

Replacing `.+` with `$0,` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the multi cursors in ST to do it. Highlight the region, go to `Selection -> Split into Lines` (there's a key binding for this, but it's platform specific. It'll be listed next to the menu entry), press right, and insert the comma.

Answer (score 1):

I tried in eclipse in mac it working fine for me.

```
Find: '(.)$'
Replace with: '$1");'
```

My case I have to add '");' at the end of line. You can replace, as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried doing this **(\d+)\n** and replacing it with **$1,** but this doesn't
>   work. Any idea why?

Single line search stops at `\n`, hence it can't be part of regex. Instead, try using end of line specifier `$`

```
s/(\d+)$/$1,/
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> is the command to open the find what and replace with panel.

Answer (score -1):

I can use the next macro:

```
[
{
    "args": null,
    "command": "split_selection_into_lines"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "by": "characters",
        "forward": true
    },
    "command": "move"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "characters": ","
    },
    "command": "insert"
},
{
    "args":
    {
        "extend": false,
        "to": "eof"
    },
    "command": "move_to"
}
]
```

save in comma.sublime-macro and edit **Key Bindings - User**

{
    "keys":["super+,"],"command":"run_macro_file","args":{"file":"Packages/user/comma.sublime-macro"}
},

PD: you need previum select your lines to add comma.

Comment: because -1 ?? You can check here the output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ri0cn4n1e9n0i1r/Kazam_screencast_00000.mp4?dl=0

That's wrong?

Comment: I guess the downvote is for the way of the solution... for me it seems to work, but also seems to be to much for such a small problem