# How to add a string to the end of each line in VS Code using regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I'm using the replacement feature. The regex option is activated and the parameters are as follows.

> Find: ^.*$
>   Replace: \0 Donkey

While the editor seems to recognize the patters (judging by the highlight), there's no substitution being made. It works using other patterns but not the one including the line end.

I've also tried combinations including but not limited to the following.

> Find: ^(.*)$
>   Replace: $0 Donkey

How can I do that?

*A programmer had a problem once.

He said: "let's use regular expressions".

Then he had two problems...*

Comment: Use `$&` instead of `$0`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Just tested. Doesn't seem to work, though. Regrettably...

Comment: Replacing `.+`  with `$& Donkey` works, same as replacing with `$0 Donkey`

Comment: Seems `*` quantifier alone has some issues. But `^.*.$` is fine.

Comment: Seems like the bug is fixed on the newer versions of VS Code. I can repro the same in 1.2.0.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using version 1.5.3 (22nd Sep 2016). Could it be something like that? It doesn't work the way you describe on my machine. How crazy is that?

Comment: @revo Oh, gosh, I'm so tired of them putting in all the bugs in the code. Why don't they skip that and focus on putting in new functionality, instead. Bugs are just annoyance. Tell them to stop!

Comment: I must admit this is the craziest bug I have seen of late. :) I think the only work around is by using two separate regex replacements: 1) `.+` -> `$0 Donkey`, 2) `^$` -> `$0 Donkey` to replace first non-empty lines, and then the empty ones.

Comment: Mine is v0.3.0. Early days...

Comment: "A programmer had a problem once..." LoL

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This patter does work on my VS Code but only on lines that actually contain something. Empty lines stay empty.

> Find: ^(.*)$
>   Replace: $0 Donkey

Comment: I think you used `^(.+)$`, right? The `^.*$` and `^(.*)$` do not work.

Comment: $0 Donkey and $1 Donkey both append \sDonkey to every line in my VSCode with @Andy J's Find   Use ^(.+)$ if you want to append to lines with something in them only.   VSC 1.5.3

Comment: Could you please confirm the version of your VSC? Mine is 1.2.0.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used star, not plus. Just as quoted. The other two you mention do work on my environemnt. What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Mine is 1.2.0. Also, I cannot make `^$|^.+$` work, either. Strange as they work when I use them separately.

Comment: @Mark I poo you not! I **know** that it's supposed to work like you said by on my system it actually skips the empty lines even when I use the star. An unsaved file, no file extension - if it's of any difference... Weird.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 1.5.3. You?

Comment: OK, that seems a bug that existed in older versions. Updating should fix it,

Comment: @Andy I just tried on an unsaved, no file extension "file" and got the expected behavior in both cases.

Comment: @Mark I'm getting the same results as AndyJ and I have the same version. What version are you running? Mine is from 22nd Sep.

Comment: @Konrad 1.5.3  The latest I believe.

Comment: any idea on finishing it by multi column select?

Answer (score 28):

The easiest way to do it is like this:

> Find: .$
> Replace: $&Donkey

Answer (score 11):

You can use:

$ = end of line
^ = begin of line

Answer (score 7):

To add text at the end of each line and also at the beginning, in Visual Studio

find (with regex option activated)

```regex
^(.+)$
```

replace

```regex
Alpha $1 Zeta
```

###### Result

Before

```
some text
```

After

```
Alpha some text Zeta
```

Image screenshot result

[image: Image screenshot result]

Answer (score 5):

Add single quotes in beginning and end with comma.

**Find:** (.*)$

**Replace:** '$1',

**I want this:**

```
 273794103
 418892296
 134582886
```

**to be:**

```
 '273794103',
 '418892296',
 '134582886',
```

I needed this for writing `SQL` query, instead of typing comma manually for 50 Ids :).

*Reference: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750491/adding-comma-to-each-line-using-sublime-text-2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and AI.*

Comment: I don't see how that addresses the actual question being asked. The point was to **include** the line-break as a part of the matched string and then to **render** it as a part of the produced output.

Comment: Also, I wonder about the "reference: AI" part. Is this a GTP-based answer? If so, I need to point out that it's not allowed on this site (and for good reasons, as it rarely produces a reliable and qualitative answer). Or did you find another source of AI-knowledge? If so, please share the link. I'd love to AI up my code (in a reliable way, of course).

Comment: @KonradViltersten , Although the accepted is correct , But I just answered this , i thought others may benefit from for similar issue for different type of output. . Also reference was mix of Human and Answer from Chat GPT. I have carefully checked what AI has generated and tested it and gave it as answer.

Comment: The thought of broading the scope for others' use is exhilarating, so I'll even +1 you on this. However, be careful with those AI aided answers. You (apparently) know to skeptically review what the stupid GPT poops out. However, it's a sensitive and thin border - you don't want to be **mis**taken for one of those dilettantes who thoughtlessly drop junk into the black box entirely ignorant of the response's quality but moronically trusting that the produced result is useful.

Answer (score 2):

To add quotes to the start of every line:

[image]

To add quotes to the end of every line:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

as i came here with fraction of the question search,
have given this answer for new bee;
this will also work:

1. press "ctrl+H" (find and replace);
2. type "\n" (without quotes) and,
3. beside find box, click and turn on, "use regular expression", as shown in picture below;
4. now, in replace box, type your text (e.g. Donkey) and don't forget to add the same "\n" (without quotes) at the end.
   [image]