# Append string to words in snippets

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am currently working on some Python snippets for VSCode using JavaScript regular expressions and I'd like to have one like :

Given

```py
var1, var2, var3
```

Produce

```py
self.var1 = var1
self.var2 = var2
self.var3 = var3
```

I currently know how to replace commas with line jump but not how to replace each word with another string. I'm pretty bad at regular expressions so it doesn't help. I think I'll need something that does the following :

```
var1, var2 -> self.var1 = var1, self.var2 = var2
```

Thanks for your help

Edit :
From suggestions in comments I tried this : `/(.*,)/self.$0 = $0/`
It obviously doesn't work for several reasons : it matches all strings up to the last comma. VSCode doesn't give access to  "\w" but i don't see how it would help.
Other thing I tested that couldn't work either since I'm looking for duplicating each of the words : `/(.*)/self.$0 = $0/`

And since I didn't post it, here is the comme replacement by a new line :
`/[,]/\n/g`

Edit2 (updated) :
From comment suggestions I tried : `/(.*?)(?:, |$)/self.$1 = $1\n/g` which leads to almost perfect result :

```py
toto, titi, tata
```

leads to

```py
self.toto = toto
self.titi = titi
self.tata = tata
self. =
```

Comment: Please let us know what you tried to see where the issue is.

Comment: I actually don't know how to try anything. As I said, I can replace commas with line jump (which is quite easy) but I don't know where to start. I'd like to select the beginning of each word and replace it with "self." as well as duplicating each word and appending an "=" before. But I don't know how to do it

Comment: Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837571/how-to-add-a-string-to-the-end-of-each-line-in-vs-code-using-regex) will give you a jumpstart. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean), you will find all the rest.

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't help at all since I already went through the entire regex doc of JS and Python. I want ti duplicate a word and insert string before/after it. None of the thing I read answers this nor leads to an idea.

Comment: Why? Look, the first post tells you how to duplicate: once there is a match, `$0` is the backreference to the whole match. When you use it in the replacement pattern, you basically insert the match value. All you need is now a pattern to match what you need. If you need to match any word, use `\w+` (and that is clear once you open any basic regex tutorial, see http://regexone.com, e.g.)

Comment: Ok so it was not clear at all since you linked something to add string at the end of a line. I tested what you explained but it does not work since I am matching any word, just as you said. But what I want is to duplicate each of the words : "toto, tata, titi" should give "toto toto, tata tata, titi titi" and it gives "toto, tata, titi toto, tata, titi"

Comment: Very good, please update the question with what you tried, what you got, and what you expected to get.

Comment: Try the following:
/(.*?)(?:, |$)/self.$0 = $0\n/

Comment: I think we have something here, thanks @HarmvanderWal. Sadly it doesn't exactly work. I'll update the question

Comment: Sorry, I matched the wrong group. It should be: /(.*?)(?:, |$)/self.$1 = $1\n/

Comment: Due to VSCode limitations, it seems I can't to use \1 ($1 is already used for another purpose) but your fix almost works

Comment: $0 is the full match on the regex. $1 is just the first captured group. How do you have $1 with another purpose? This is all I can do with the limited information you gave.

Comment: In VSCode snippets $1 is a place holder for the cursor (multicursor edition) and tab-stop functionnality. Thanks a lot, it honestly almost works, I'll try on VSCode forums/github to know is someone has an idea. You awesome @HarmvanderWal

Comment: All for the upvotes ;)
Also: to not match on empty lines, try the following: /(.+?)(?:, |$)/self.$1 = $1\n/

Comment: My bad, using $1 actually works. I'll update the post but I still have an issue. An extra line is added

Comment: If you want do have it done in 1 regex, this is the best I can do. If you use 2, it's a lot easier:
1: /, /\n/ 
2: /^.+$/self.$0 = $0/

Comment: Use `\s*([^,\s]+)(?:,|$)` and replace with `self.$1 = $1\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your `python.json` snippet file

```
  "var-init": {
    "prefix": "varinit",
    "body": [
      "${1/([\\w_]+)(?:[,\\s]|$)/self.$1 = $1\n/g}",
      "$0"
    ],
    "description": "var initialisation"
  }
```

- Type the prefix: `varinit`
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Type the variables you want separated by `,` with or without spaces: `titi,tata,toto`
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Result

```
self.titi = titi
self.tata = tata
self.toto = toto
```

And the cursor on the next line.

**Edit**

A simplification of the regex and using the tip from Mark about the if-replacement `${2:+\n}`

```
"${1/([\\w_]+)([, ])*/self.$1 = $1${2:+\n}/g}"
```

now the variables can be separated with spaces or `,`

Comment: Looks familiar...  I would suggest `    "${1/\\s*([^,]+)(,)*/self.$1 = $1${2:+\n}/g}",` as the regex is a little simpler and it doesn't add an extra newline after the last variable.  And the spaces are handled much better.  I get spaces added to the beginning of subsequent lines with your code.

Comment: It is also easy to modify this to where the variables are already listed and selected.  If that is a use case for the OP.  For more complicated cases of using variable numbers of arguments in a class constructor snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998252/vscode-snippet-add-variable-number-of-objects-to-a-class-constructor/58459793#58459793 and for a class initializer see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225204/make-a-vscode-snippet-that-can-use-a-variable-number-of-arguments/58228253#58228253

Answer (score 0):

You may use

**Find What**: `\s*([^,\s]+)(?:,|$)`
**Replace With**: `self.$1 = $1\n`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9am3tC/1).

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `([^,\s]+)` - capturing group 1: one or more chars other than whitespace and comma
- `(?:,|$)` - a non-capturing group matching `,` or end of line.

[image]